# ¿Cómo se puede cambiar el color de un elemento dinámico sin DOM? Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, algoritmos

Hola buenas necesito ayuda porque me encuentro trabado con el código, estoy haciendo un trabajo práctico y necesito que las canciones ingresadas se acumulen y si la duración de una canción es mayor a 180 segundos que cambie de color (Sin DOM me tira "Uncaught ReferenceError"). gracias

```js
'use strict';

    let listadoDiscos =[];

    // Función Cargar:

    function Cargar() {
        let discos = new Disco();

        discos.establecerNombreDisco();
        discos.establecerAutor();
        discos.establecerCodigo();
        discos.establecerDuracionPista();
        discos.establecerCancion();

        listadoDiscos.push(discos);
    };

    // Función Mostrar:
    const Mostrar = () => {
        let html = ``;

        for(let disco of listadoDiscos){
            html += disco.OGhtml();
        }

        html+= `<hr> <br> <p>Cantidad de discos: ${Disco.cantidadDiscos}</p>`;

        document.querySelector('#pistas').innerHTML = html; 
    };

    class Disco{
        static cantidadDiscos = 0;
        static codigos = [];
        #nombre = '';
        #autor = '';
        #codigo = '';
        #duracion = '';
        #cancion = '';
        #time = '';

        constructor() {
            console.log('Se ha creado un disco nuevo');
            Disco.cantidadDiscos ++
        }

        establecerNombreDisco() {
            do{ this.#nombre = prompt('Por favor escriba el nombre del disco');
            } while(!isNaN(this.#nombre));
        }

        establecerAutor(){
            do{ this.#autor = prompt('Ahora escriba el nombre del autor');
            }
            while(!isNaN(this.#autor));
        }

        establecerCodigo() {
            let existeCodigo = false;
            do {
                existeCodigo = false;
                this.#codigo = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese el codigo del disco del 1 al 999.'));
                
                for (let codigo of Disco.codigos) {
                    if (this.#codigo == codigo) {
                        alert('El codigo ya se encuentra registrado, Porfavor intente con uno nuevo');
                        existeCodigo = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (!(this.#codigo >= 1 && this.#codigo <= 999) || existeCodigo);
            Disco.codigos.push(this.#codigo);
            console.log(Disco.codigos);
            
        }
              
        establecerDuracionPista(){
            let bandera = false;
            do{ this.#duracion = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese la duración del disco. 100 minutos como maximo'));
            if (this.#duracion > 100){
                bandera = true;
                alert ('Error, número invalido');
            }else (this.#duracion <= 100);{
            }

            }while (!(this.#duracion >= 0 && this.#duracion <= 100)){
                bandera = true;
            }   

    }
        establecerCancion() {    
            var songs = 0;

            do{ this.#cancion = prompt('Ingrese una canción del disco');
                songs += this.#cancion;
                songs++;
                if(confirm === true){
                break;
            }else(confirm === false)
            this.#time = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuantos minutos dura la canción?'));
            if(this.#time >= 180){
                return true;
            }
        }while(confirm('¿Desea ingresar otra canción?'));
         
        
        //establecerCancion() {
            //do{ this.#cancion = prompt('Ingrese una canción del disco');
            //if(confirm === true){
               // break;
            //}else(confirm === false)
            //this.#time = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuantos minutos dura la canción?'));
        
        //}while(confirm('¿Desea ingresar otra canción?'));      
      
        }
            obtenerNombreDisco(){
                return this.#nombre;
            }

            obtenerAutor(){
                return this.#autor
            }

            obtenerCodigo() {
                return this.#codigo;
            } 

            obtenerDuracion() {
                return this.#duracion;
            }  
            
            obtenerCancion() {
                return this.#cancion;
            } 

            obtenerTime() {
                return this.#time;
            } 
            
            OGhtml(){

                let html = `<hr> <br> <p><h4><strong>Nombre del disco: </strong> ${this.#nombre} </h4>`;

                html += `<p> <h4><strong>Autor: </strong> ${this.#autor} </h4>`;

                html += `<h4> <strong>Duración: ${this.#duracion} </h4>`;

                html += `<h4> <strong>Codigo: </strong> ${this.#codigo} </h4>`;

                html += `<h4> <strong>Canciones: </strong></h4> <br>
                <h5>${songs}  -  <span class="time">${this.#time}min.</span></h5>`;

                document.querySelector('#pistas').innerHTML = html; 

            return html;
            }
    }
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0%;
    }

    header {
        background-color:#007bff ;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: left;
        padding: 2%;
        color: white;
    }

    h1{
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .text-center{
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .text-right{
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .container{
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    footer {
        background-color:#007bff ;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: left;
        padding: 1%;
        color: white;
        margin-bottom: 0%;
    }

    h2{
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    h4{
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Programación I</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css"/>
            <script src="parcial.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1 class="text-center">Programación I</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <main id="items" class="col">

                <h2 class="fw-bold fs-1">Mis discos</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-primary px-5" onclick="Cargar();">Cargar nuevo disco</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary px-5 mx-3" onclick="Mostrar();">Mostrar discos</button>
                <div id="pistas"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
                <h2>ZZZ</h2>
            
                <h3>DWT2B</h3>
            </footer>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: El error te está dando porque dentro de la función `OGhtml()` estás tratando de usar una variable llamada `songs` que no está disponible en el contexto de la función (el propio error te lo está indicando). A lo mejor en vez de usar `songs` pretendías usar `this.#cancion`.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo puede solucionar